# How to use sns message filter to send to particular email?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Is it possible to send different message to different email endpoints having different subscription ARN.If possible suggest some way using message filtering.

All emails subscribed to same Topic .But requirement is to send rewards points balance based on email which is being fetched from a query either rest or dynamodb query.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to customize Amazon SNS messages per-user. All recipients will receive the same message.

Yes, you can use Amazon SNS **filtering** to control *which* recipients get each message, but that isn't really a good idea for sending single messages.

I would recommend that you investigate [Amazon Pinpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/welcome.html):

> Amazon Pinpoint is an AWS service that you can use to engage with your customers across multiple messaging channels. You can use Amazon Pinpoint to send push notifications, emails, SMS text messages, and voice messages.

It might be a better way to engage with your customers.

Comment: Thanks will try that option but just wanted to avoid multiple subscription confirmation to user